# How to queue requests in React Native without Redux?

Tags: react-native, request, request-queueing

Let's say I have a notes app. I want to enable the user to make changes while he is offline, save the changes optimistically in a Mobx store, and add a request to save the changes (on the server) to a queue.
Then when the internet connection is re-established I want to run the requests in the queue one by one so the data in the app syncs with data on the server.

Any suggestions would help.

I tried using [react-native-job-queue](https://github.com/SimonErm/react-native-job-queue) but it doesn't seem to work.
I also considered [react-native-queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue) but the library seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was in the wrong. The [react-native-job-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-job-queue) library does work, I just made a mistake by trying to pass a function reference (API call) to the Worker instead of just passing an object that contains the request URL and method and then just implement the Worker to make the API call based on those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate store (or an array in AsyncStorage) for pending operations, and add the operations to an array there when the network is disconnected. Tell your existing stores to look there for data, so you can render it optimistically. Then, when you detect a connection, run the updates in array order, and clear the array when done.

You could also use your existing stores, and add something like `pending: true` to values that haven't posted to your backend. However, you'll have less control over the order of operations, which sounds like it is important.